# Enumerating (looping through) an IQueryable<Type> instance

Tags: iqueryable, lightswitch-2013

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(string Filter1, ref IQueryable<Type> query)
{
    //how can I loop through the query and add data to a custom list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the _PreprocessQuery method is for defining the contents of the query and not doing anything with those contents (which would be Post processing). So a simple method might read:

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(string Filter1, ref IQueryable<Type> query)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.FilterColumn == Filter1);
}
```

This is happening on the server side so even if you did intercept the results, I think it would be tricky to get any list you created back to the client side.

Once the query results have been passed to the client screen, you can then loop through the query and use the contents however you like, for example using Screen Property methods like Query1_Loaded or Collection methods like Query1_Changed depending on what you're trying to achieve. Untested code, but something like this:

```
    partial void Query1_Loaded(bool succeeded)
    {
        // Loop through the rows on the screen ...
        foreach (IEntityObject rowData in this.Query1)
        {
            // Reference individual values like this ...
            string FilterResult = rowData.Details.Properties["FilterColumn"].Value.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```